# How to remove Spin Web of Broodmother in DotA 2?

Tags: dota-2

In this link, [Destroy Spin Web](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Spin_Web#Destroy_Spin_Web), it is written you can manually destroy Spin Web of Broodmother. It is also written in tooltip of Spin Web when you hover over the ability. I can't seem to find this Destroy Spin Web ability.

Also, what are the ways I can remove web as Broodmother and as her enemy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Destroy Spin Web can only be used by the web itself; each web has a unit box right in the middle: select it and use the skill from there.

Enemies cannot destroy Broodmother's webs in any way.